# The RX and receiver circuit is not working

Tags: circuit-analysis

I was working on a IR emitting and recieving circuit with the help of RX/TX and a SM0038 IR receiver and observing the flow of current in a LED but the problem is the LED never gets lit. 
If the circuit diagram helps...

[image: circuit diagram]

Comment: What voltage is the battery/supply?

Comment: Your figure indicates you've connected the NPN's emitter to the battery's positive terminal, and its collector to the battery's negative terminal. Normally, when using an NPN transistor as a switch, you connect its emitter directly to GROUND (the battery's negative terminal, in this case) with no other components between the emitter and GROUND, and its collector to one side of the load, and the other side of the load connects to the V+ power rail (the battery's positive terminal, in this case).

Comment: @SolveEtCoagula07 9 volt

Comment: Rotate that picture or use the tool in the question and draw a schematic

Answer (score 1):

The [SM0038 IR receiver](https://www.robot-r-us.com/downloads/e/990-sm0038-ir-receiver/download.html) is designed to receive a signal with 38 kHz carrier, +- 3 kHz. The rest is filtered out by sophisticated circuitry.

[image]

To get any signal out of this, your IR LED transmitter must be driven with 38 kHz rectangular signal. The DC signal won't make it through. The information must be encoded using any sort of pulse modulation, whichever you are comfortable with.